# mysql encrypted table name and columns

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, special-characters

I'm making a C# application and i want to encrypt table name and column name
Now my query looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'fmx8ttwCrwiloPwF0cJzRA==' ('0W7pGx8jrh2+NiWh57iUhA==' INT auto_increment, 'nAra1k/bvX0hVmIgB6cVdw==' INT, 'ypDGo22BnDzv6lkYrRVOvg==' LONGTEXT)  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What is wrong with it?

How can I fix it?

I need to use special charset...

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that...?  Encrypt your **data**, not your **structure**...

Comment: Someone can have acces to my data base so i want to encrypt it - with collums and table names...

column name can talk what data is encrypted

Comment: You want backticks rather than single quotes (which I consider a typographical error).  You should develop an API into the database using views and stored procedures -- with reasonable names -- and set security on the database so nothing else can see the structure.  Maintaining application code like this is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: The problem with your code is likely the use of a single quote verses a backtick (`).  But this still doesn't make much sense to me to do it this way.